# Python/Terminal trouble, Python2 and 3, Traceback error occurs after opening Terminal and writing script

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, terminal

I'm super new to Python and I tried installing Python3 onto my Mac. I try to open my Terminal and write script and the below happens. I'm not sure what's going on. Any ideas/insight?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SO is probably not the right place to be asking questions like this, but you should be writing:

print(3+3)

lower-case is important

Comment: thank you! any suggestions as to where to ask questions like this? very new to the whole thing

Comment: For very basic questions like this you can just google around or search the python docs https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html, you can find the answer there pretty easily.